# VBA code to key in a 19 digit number using "loop" in a excel cell, without converting it into value like "1.591E+17"?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

This is my piece of code.

```
For i = 0 To Val(TextBox2.Value)    
var1 = TextBox1.Value + i 
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@" 
ActiveCell.Value2 = var1 
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate 
Next i
```

My input is "159100000000000000" and what I expect is - "X" numbers after that.
I should get the values in cells like

```
159100000000000000
159100000000000001
159100000000000002
159100000000000003
.
.
.
```

Even I tried to change the number format of my cell to "Text" in run time. Still am getting values like

> '1.591E+17 '1.591E+17 '1.591E+17 '1.591E+17

Can anybody help me in this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store these numbers this size as a number because they are too large for an Integer to hold and are too precise for a Double. The only way to do this would be to increment the last few digits and keep a prefix as a string.

Something like (untested):

```
Dim prefix As String
Dim startValue As Long
Dim endValue As Long

prefix = Left(TextBox1.Value, 12)
startValue = Val(Right(TextBox1.Value, 7))
endValue = startValue + Val(TextBox2.Value)

For i = startValue To endValue
    ActiveCell.Value2 = prefix & Format(i, "0000000")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next
```

This will only work if the text is always 19 digits, otherwise the `prefix`, `startValue` and `endValue` variables will need to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: It seems like the problem is with the cell holding the value as a number, not with getting the value into the cell.  It seems like your solution ultimately outputs a string due to concatenation, but is complex in accomplishing this.

Comment: @n8 The number is too large to be operated upon in that way. Excel does not handle arbitrarily large integers; you only get 15 digits of precision.

Comment: OK, but if the textbox value is a string and the cell is formatted as text then there is no reason to make it a number.  The only challenge is to ensure Excel doesn't try and be helpful and convert it to a number.

Comment: @n8 How *exactly* do you want `var1 = TextBox1.Value + i` to work without Excel treating it as a number at some point?

Comment: OK, I'm seeing your point, vba converts it to a Long, which is presented in scientific form.  In the case that the TextBox1.value is 999999999999999999 (or something similarly problematic where textbox + i will cause a number in a unevaluated position "x" to roll) there is likely a need for a recursive function that will start with len(i) and exit when the 1 no longer carries.  I jumped the gun, this is not a simple problem.

Comment: @Phylogenesis It worked with your suggestion. Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 0):

You can format the NumberFormat and specifically define how many places you want to format out to:

```
For i = 0 To Val(TextBox2.Value)    
var1 = TextBox1.Value + i 
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "00000000000000000.0"
ActiveCell.Value2 = var1 
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate 
Next i
```

Comment: @Phylogenesis It worked with your suggestion. Thanks for your advise.